# How do you pull the subject line of an RSS feed "blog" into an ExactTarget email with AmpScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud

One of our templates utilizes Amp Scripting to pull the subject line from an RSS feed.  The code we use for the subject is as follows:

```
%%=v(@title)=%% %%=Format(Now(1), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
```

When we send test emails it pulls everything is fine.  However, once we send it for real the only thing that appears when the email goes out is the date.  It completely ignores the code for the title.  It would appear that the first portion of the script is being bypassed.  Thoughts?

Comment: How does the rest of the code look?  Not quite enough to go on.

Comment: Here is part of it: <h1 style="font-weight: bold; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%% style="color: #006599; text-decoration:none;">%%=v(@title)=%%</a></h1>
<span style="font-size:13px; color: #000; font-family: arial, sans-serif;">%%=v(@desc)=%%</span>
%%[ 
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you don't get the first part set in the non-test send then most likely the variable @title is not setup. As Kelly suggested it would help if you can post the actual AMP script which does the subject retrieval from RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending your email through an interaction, declaring the variable in the body of the email will not produce the value in the subject line.

You must declare variable within the subject line text box.

```
%%[
SET @title =Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(HTTPGet("https://www.yourblog.com/blog.xml"),"//item/title",1),1),"Value")
]%%

%%=v(@title)=%% %%=Format(Now(1), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  Please consider posting it as a new question.